# Cannot remember the name of a CLI recorder software

Tags: command-line, video, software-rec, recording

I stumbled across a useful command line recorder that allows the user to copy the text when watching the 'recording'. I just cannot remember the name of the project. I just remember you can play and pause the video and the user can copy and paste the text in the video.

Anyone know the name of the project?

Comment: Is this making a video from what you do on the commandline? Or is this recording USB Camera input that only has a commandline interface?  I have no idea what 'the text' in the first sentence referring to as you have not indicate any text before that. Does the text (whatever it is referring to) get rendered as characters in the recorded video? As comment on the video stream?

Comment: To clarify you make a video of the command-line like this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5YyZZYX8a0o the only difference was that the user could copy the text in the recording. I dont think it used a video codec in the traditional sense. My guess is that it maybe used a HTML 5 technology to print the text to a webpage in a video like fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might it be [asciinema](https://asciinema.org/), [showterm](http://showterm.io/) or [PLAYTERM](http://playterm.org/)/[ttyrec](http://0xcc.net/ttyrec/)? Coincidentally a colleague of mine is right now trying to remember something like this as well.

Comment: Spot on thats what I was after. Pretty sure it was showterm i saw but asciinema looks decent as well. Thanks for your answer :D

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [`recordmydesktop`](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php). You can get a window id using `wmctrl` or `xwininfo` and then use that `id`:

```
recordmydesktop --windowid <id_of_window>
```

you can use `--pause-shortcut` to define a key combination for pause/continue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however that is not the project I found . I will recognize it as soon as I see the website.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `script` and `scriptreplay` to capture and replay a CLI session.  It should already be in your system as part of util-linux.  It does not offer play/pause features, though.

```
script -t 2> timefile
```

to start the recording (type 'exit' to stop recording) using the default filename `typescript` and the timing file `timefile`

```
scriptreplay timefile
```

To replay the session.